# How do I build a SSDT VS 2015 package to production server?

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to build a SSDT (SSIS) package from Visual Studio 2015 to my prod server that runs Sql Server 2016. I'm coming from a SSIS 2008 r2 environment that allowed me to build my packages and then copy the files over to the server and execute the *.SSISDeploymentManifest. Now when I hit Deploy in VS, it goes through the wizard, but it's asking for destination server information. I cannot connect directly to the prod server from VS or SSMS due to security. Is there a way to get VS to deploy(or build) the package and .ispac file locally and then I can manually more it to the appropriate server and then execute it?

So far, my only work around is to Build the package. However, I have found that it puts the .dtsx file in the obj\Development folder and the .ispac file in the bin\Development folder. Going back and forth to copy files for numerous packages is painful and I'm sure not the intended process.

Comment: Any help with this?

Comment: Are you using the SSIS Catalog for SQL 2016? If you use the Project level deployment in the Catalog, it's designed to just deploy the ispac straight into the catalog and work from that.  You should just need to use the ispac to deploy the packages as it contains all of the packages inside it.

Comment: @PeterSchott So do I just grab the ispac file from the Development folder? I was expecting to deploy and then see it in the Deployment folder but it never shows up there.

Comment: The ispac is the binary generated when you build. It is a glorified (and renamed) zip file that contains all of your dtsx packages + some config information. You should be able to use that to deploy to the SSIS Catalog. Now if you're doing something else to run packages, that will be a different issue, but it should contain all DTSX files in your project.